# Can pg_hba.conf trust processes?

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to configure PostgreSQL such that it can trust a single process, instead of a specific user?

Comment: Not that I know of. But you could run the specific process with a specific user?

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible I am afraid of.  The selection is based on the following criteria:

1. Type of connection (local or network)
2. Username requested
3. Database requested

Nowhere in there is a process given.  If you want to trust a given process the way to do that is to have a service account, a specific database user, and map these in, using `peer` authentication on *nix (`peer` on local connections used to be called `ident` but this was changed since `ident` is very different on network connections and has far more issues).